# Passing -J parameters programmatically to JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm using programmatic way to run JMeter defined in the step 4 of [this post](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui).
The code looks as follows:

```
final StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();
JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome(getAbsolutePath("/jmeter"));
JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties(getAbsolutePath("/jmeter/bin/jmeter.properties"));
JMeterUtils.initLocale();
try {
    SaveService.loadProperties();
    final File jmeterConfig = new File(getAbsolutePath(pathToJmx));
    final HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(jmeterConfig);
    jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
} catch (final IOException e) {
    throw new JMeterConfigurationException(e);
}
jmeter.run();
```

I want to provide the values for `${__P(parameter_name)}` parameters I specified in `.jmx` file, that can be done using [-J parameter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) in console.

How can I pass values for this parameters in the code above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given you already use [JMeterUtils](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/util/JMeterUtils.html) class you should be able to call [JMeterUtils.setProperty()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/util/JMeterUtils.html#setProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) function like:

```
JMeterUtils.setProperty("parameter_name","foo");
```

And then in your script refer the property using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) as `${__P(parameter_name,)}`

You can also add the next line:

```
parameter_name=foo
```

to the *jmeter.properties* file which you're loading with `JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties` function.

**Dont' forget to add [ApacheJMeter_functions.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_functions/4.0) to your project classpath** otherwise `__P()` function will not be resolved.

More information: [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: I've added the ApacheJMeter_functions.jar, set the property using JMeterUtils, but the property isn't substituted during the runtime and I get an exception like this `Non HTTP response message: ${__P(tested-service-host,,)}` when I parametrize target server host.
Do you have any ideas why it doesn't work?

Comment: but when I run JMeter from command line and supply -Jtested-service-host=localhost, the property is substituted with localhost and everything works fine

Comment: I've added ApacheJMeter_functions.jar to the maven project I work with, but do I need to register it anywhere when I run JMeter so it will be aware of this library?

Comment: added ApacheJMeter_functions.jar to the lib/ext directory under JMeter home and it started working, thank you :)

Comment: I'm very happy I found this. I have struggled to get __P to work, and now I know that I need to put the ApacheJMeter_functions.jar in the ext/lib path of JMeter home. If a test is run in Java, it is possible to set this home, such as in the src/resources path, and then create src/resources/ext/lib and put the jar there, and it works. Finally. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: If you execute your test from java code, you can add ApacheJMeter_functions as dependency and configure the function search path: `JMeterUtils.setProperty("search_paths",Property.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());`